Understanding different ways of coding categorical predictors in regression
Using this code and sample data:
hsb2 <- read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsb2.csv")
# creating the factor variable
hsb2$race.f <- factor(hsb2$race)

#creating the contrast matrix manually by modifying the dummy coding scheme
c<-contr.treatment(4)
my.coding<-matrix(rep(1/4, 12), ncol=3)
my.simple<-c-my.coding
my.simple

contrasts(hsb2$race.f)<-my.simple
m1=lm(write~race.f, hsb2)    
summary(m1)

We get:
my.simple
      2     3     4
1 -0.25 -0.25 -0.25
2  0.75 -0.25 -0.25
3 -0.25  0.75 -0.25
4 -0.25 -0.25  0.75


summary(m1))
 Call:
lm(formula = write ~ race.f, data = hsb2)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-23.0552  -5.4583   0.9724   7.0000  18.8000 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  51.6784     0.9821  52.619  < 2e-16 ***
race.f2      11.5417     3.2861   3.512 0.000552 ***
race.f3       1.7417     2.7325   0.637 0.524613    
race.f4       7.5968     1.9889   3.820 0.000179 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 9.025 on 196 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1071,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.0934 
F-statistic: 7.833 on 3 and 196 DF,  p-value: 5.785e-05

But if you were only interested in the contrast coded in col 4 of my.simple (-.25,-.25, -.25,.75), and thus wrote
hsb2$race.fx=as.numeric(ifelse(hsb2$race.f=="1","-.25",ifelse(hsb2$race.f=="2","-.25",ifelse(hsb2$race.f=="3","-.25",".75"))))
m2=lm(write~race.fx, hsb2)    
    summary(m2)

we get
summary(m2)

Call:
lm(formula = write ~ race.f2, data = hsb2)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-23.0552  -5.4000   0.7724   7.9448  17.6000 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   50.564      0.957  52.834  < 2e-16 ***
race.f2        4.655      1.468   3.171  0.00176 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 9.27 on 198 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.04833,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.04353 
F-statistic: 10.06 on 1 and 198 DF,  p-value: 0.00176

This result seems counter-intuitive to me, shouldn't the effect of race.fx be comparable to race.f4?
Can anyone explain what I am not understanding in this example?

This isn't a variable-coding issue: you have fit two distinct models.
